How does deviceinfo.me detect mobile model?
I was wondering, if anyone has any clue as to how would one detect a mobile phone model using javascript?
Everywhere I look, people are recommending to detect this from user agent.
I have noticed that when you simulate mobile device using devTools, user agent returns model number.
But this is not a case in real world.
In real world, the model number is omitted and you cannot detect the model from userAgent.
But there is this site, deviceinfo.me that detects my mobile model, even though my user agent does not provide it.
Does anyone have any idea how do they manage to do this?


Go the the network panel, and inspect the GET request for https://www.deviceinfo.me that your browser makes. There's lots of sec-ch-ua-... request headers being send, that contain the relevant information. This is information voluntarily provided by the client - "user agent client hints", https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Client_hints#user-agent_client_hints, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers#user_agent_client_hints
